# Duplicate pages in Report SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I am working on Reporting Services and create Report. Here is Report properties: A4 Landscape, Width = 29.7 cm, Height = 21 cm and all margins is 0 cm. In body Width = 29.7 cm and Height = 21 cm. Body is divided into two parts.Each part have Tablix within Rectangle. Problem is, when I run report, I get same two pages as a result. How to solve this problem. I need to get only one page as a result. Pls help.

Comment: You are saying `body` is divided in two parts having `tablix` in each part. So in your case are both the `tablix` returning same data in different pages by any chance?

Comment: Yes. I get two identical pages in report (with same data). I am confused and dont know how resolve this problem.

Comment: Does your two different `tablix` returning same data which is getting displayed? Might be you can provide some screenshots or `tablix dataset`.

Comment: Yes, I have different tablix which returning same date in two pages. I will share two pictures from dropbox, which visually show my problem. I get two identical pages as result.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/wyutlt3lfrt17la/PutniNalogPage1.png?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/3vhvxutraobyob1/PutniNalogPage2.png?dl=0

Comment: Yes, I have different tablix which returning same DATA in two pages.

Comment: @logixmind Are your two tablix side-by-side (Left and Right) or are they up-and-down (Top and Bottom)? Are two tablix have data coming from two different dataset or same dataset?

Comment: I don't see any need to show two different `tablix` with same set of data in two separate pages, why not remove any one of them this way your report will come in one page. Also the snapshot links you provided does say - "link not found(The file you’re looking for has been moved or deleted.)"

Comment: Hello guys, I solve that problem. @AnupAgrawal, I have two tablix side-by-side (Left and right) which using same dataset. Actually, in report, I have 4  rectangle + tablix, first two in top and other two in down place, but for simplicity I asked for the first two. First of all, for each field, I must using IIF condition (=IIF(Fields!NameOfField.Value=Previous(Fields!NameOfField.value),True,False)) that is not repeated appearance of the fields in second page of report. Secondly, my body Height had value 41cm and report Height 21 cm. I reduced value for body Height to 23cm.I deleted snapshots.

Comment: Thank you for your answers in any case...